# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown Links Don't Work

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried a number of solution to get this to work, but haven't had any luck yet.

I have altered the bootstrap.js in the dropdown section with:

```
$('html')
```

$('html')
  .on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)

I have also tried before the closing html tag: 
    $('body').on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});

Both of these work temporarily. I can get the dropdown, select the link, then go to the linked page, but then the menu stop working. The only way to get it working again is to clear my cache and refresh the page. Then it works fine again until I try it a second time. Rinse, repeat.

I am using an include for the header, nav and footer throughout the site.

Please check out http://thebibleminiseries.com, then size the browser down until you see the dropdown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your non-home pages two of your script files - bootstrap.js and main.js - cannot be found. The broken URLs are:
http://thebibleminiseries.com/the-bible-miniseries-books-studies/js/vendor/bootstrap.js
http://thebibleminiseries.com/the-bible-miniseries-books-studies/js/main.js

You need to change these lines:

```
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

I found the cause of this problem by using my browser's console feature. If you try it yourself you will also see the 404 errors.

Comment: That is what happens when you are asked to rush to get site up. :)